# Spring REST Docs: how to replace parameters

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-restdocs

In my unit tests we find

```
this.mockMvc
  .perform(post("/authenticate")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .param("username", "user@example.com")
    .param("password", "superSecretPassword"))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andDo(document("preprocessed-request",
    preprocessRequest(replacePattern(Pattern.compile("superSecretPassword"), "XXX"))));
```

cf. [Spring REST Docs documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/#customizing-requests-and-responses-preprocessors)

This generates `build/generated-snippets/preprocessed-request/http-request.adoc` with the content

```
[source,http]
----
POST /authenticate HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=user%40example.com&password=superSecretPassword
----
```

But I expect the password to be masked because of replacePattern():

```
[source,http]
----
POST /authenticate HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

username=user%40example.com&password=XXX
----
```

What can I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pattern replacement has no effect due to an unfortunate side-effect of how MockMvc handles request parameters. `replacePattern` acts on the content, i.e. body of the request, but MockMvc doesn't actually include the form-encoded parameters in the body.

Spring REST Docs is smart enough to deal with this when it's generating the snippets, e.g. for a form URL encoded `POST` request it looks at the parameters to figure out what the request's body should be. It doesn't apply these same smarts when applying `replacePattern`.

You can still mask the password by using your own `OperationPreprocessor` that changes the parameter map. For example:

```
private OperationPreprocessor maskPassword() {
    return new PasswordMaskingPreprocessor();
}

private static class PasswordMaskingPreprocessor implements OperationPreprocessor {

    @Override
    public OperationRequest preprocess(OperationRequest request) {
        Parameters parameters = new Parameters();
        parameters.putAll(request.getParameters());
        parameters.set("password", "XXX");
        return new OperationRequestFactory().create(request.getUri(),
                request.getMethod(), request.getContent(), request.getHeaders(),
                parameters, request.getParts());
    }

    @Override
    public OperationResponse preprocess(OperationResponse response) {
        return response;
    }

}
```

You can then use this new preprocessor in place of `replacePattern`:

```
this.mockMvc
  .perform(post("/authenticate")
    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    .param("username", "user@example.com")
    .param("password", "superSecretPassword"))
  .andExpect(status().isOk())
  .andDo(document("preprocessed-request",
    preprocessRequest(maskPassword())));
```

Comment: I consider it very useful to write my own `OperationPreprocessor`s. Is it possible to add it to the [Spring REST Docs documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-restdocs/docs/1.0.x/reference/html5/)?

Comment: Yes, that's possible. I've opened [an issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/156).