# Mask Headers in spring restdocs

Tags: spring-restdocs

So I was trying to follow this example:
[Spring REST Docs: how to replace parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33281509/spring-rest-docs-how-to-replace-parameters)

What I'm trying to do is to mask the JWT token in the header of my request and I have an OperationPreprocessor that looks like this:

```
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders
import org.springframework.restdocs.operation.OperationRequest
import org.springframework.restdocs.operation.OperationRequestFactory
import org.springframework.restdocs.operation.OperationResponse
import org.springframework.restdocs.operation.preprocess.OperationPreprocessor

class AuthHeaderPreprocessor implements OperationPreprocessor {
    @Override
    OperationRequest preprocess(OperationRequest request) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders()
        headers.putAll(request.getHeaders())
        headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer 12345')

        return new OperationRequestFactory().create(
            request.getUri(),
            request.getMethod(),
            request.getContent(),
            headers,
            request.getParameters(),
            request.getParts()
        )

    }

    @Override
    OperationResponse preprocess(OperationResponse response) {
        return response
    }
}
```

When I run the test they run without error but I don't see any change to the header. I'm using the OperationPreprocessor like this

```
RestAssuredRestDocumentation.document(
    'event-list', preprocessRequest(new AuthHeaderPreprocessor()), ...
```

Any ideas what I may be missing.

Comment: I can't see anything wrong in what you've shared. Could you turn it into a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) so that it's possible to see the whole picture?

Comment: Andy thanks for the reply, I'll get an example together when I can, might take me a little while, but I'll try to squeeze in time between other things, as this is not the highest priority yet... I have a tendency to get pulled off of new work and put on fixing bugs.

Comment: Totally don't understand it but now it works. There must have been something bad cached somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code I had actually worked and is a good example of how to filter headers. For some reason when testing it initially I wasn't working, but that seems like it was maybe just something cached in the build not getting cleared, as it works now.